# Why does Mirror modifier sometimes go to the wrong side?

Tags: modeling

This might be a very trivial issue, but even with origin being at the right spot, the mirror mirrors at 'random' angle.. like here:

[image: mirror modifier]

What does contribute to this behaviour? Is there an easy fix for this?

Thank you all

Comment: The object probably has a rotation, so its x axis is not aligned to the world x.

Comment: ok is there a way to reset this?

Comment: Alt + R in object mode.

Comment: oh cool, thank you very much! it worked.